# Node.js swagger ui configuration for multipart file upload not working

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

I am trying to come up with swagger yaml configuration for my Node.js express REST api's. Somehow the configuration i have written below doesn't recognise the multipart files i am trying to send to the API. Can someone verify my yaml configuration and suggest me if any correction is required? Am i using the consumes tag correctly?

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Pdf Generator
  description: Api's to generate pdf
  version: '1.0'
paths:
  /{apiVersion}/report:
    post:
      tags:
        - Pdf generator
      description: convert html to pdf
      produces:
        - application/pdf
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - name: htmlTemplateFile
          in: formData
          schema:
            type: file
          required: true
          description: html to be processed
        - name: JsonData
          in: formData
          schema:
            type: file
          required: true
          description: Json data to be processed
        - name: reportFormatType
          in: formData
          description: enter html/pdf, depending on the required output format
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
        - name: apiVersion
          description: api version
          in: path
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully created
```

Comment: You are using OpenAPI 2.0 syntax but with the `openapi: 3.0.0` directive. Is your API definition supposed to be OpenAPI 2.0 or 3.0? OAS3 uses different syntax for request bodies.

Comment: @Helen you are right. this helped to fix the issue.